# Apache HttpClient Max-Connections-per-host Behaviour

Tags: java, apache, rest, httpclient, connection-pooling

I have implemented a **REST API** ==> Say ServiceA which in turn calls another remote API ==> Say ServiceB to get the data.

ServiceA is calling ServiceB via **Apache HttpClient** (V3.1)

I am stuck up in complete understanding of below property:

> DefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost

I have configured above property as 10.

Now, according to docs:

> Defines the maximum number of connections allowed per host configuration. 
>     These values only apply to the number of connections from a particular instance 
>     of HttpConnectionManager.

Theory works well till this point.
Let's assume below points in case of ServiceB.

1. Scenario 1 (ServiceB has single instance of application server)

Straightforward. At any given point of time there can be maximum of 10 concurrent connections to ServiceB from ServiceA.

2. Scenario 2 (ServiceB has multiple instance of application server)

Since ServiceB has multiple Hosts will be possible to have more than 10 concurrent connections from ServiceA ?
Or
`DefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost` will be identified based on the domain name of ServiceB.

Also, will there be any difference when there is a Load Balancer configured for ServiceB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have answered your question yourself.
As per the documentation, the `DefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost` is maintained per `HostConfiguration` as documented here: https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HostConfiguration.html

So the granularity will be exactly the one that you use for constructing your `HostConfiguration`s. I.e. if you use one single dns name to access the service, you will get exactly `DefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost` connections to that service. If you use one dns name or even IP address per service *instance*, you will get that many times the max connections.

Same applies for a load balancer. Be careful though if you also access Service C through the same loadbalancer (referenced by the same dns name) -- Service A will still connect with only `DefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost` connections (in sum) Services B & C in that case.